# overload operator followed by template type parameters

Tags: c++

In boost::unordered_map, the template is declared like this:

```
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A>
class unordered_map
{
```

and at the bottom of the template, there's a method declared like this:

```
    friend bool operator==<K,T,H,P,A>(
            unordered_map const&, unordered_map const&);
```

Could anyone please tell me why <K, T, H, P, A> is needed here?

Thanks!

Comment: It befriends that particular specialization of `operator==`.

Answer (score 2):

As written, the line declares as a friend a particular specialization of the `operator==` function template [declared previously as](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/unordered/unordered_map_fwd.hpp)

```
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A>
bool operator==(unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A> const&,
    unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A> const&);
```

If you remove the `<K,T,H,P,A>` -

```
friend bool operator==(unordered_map const&, unordered_map const&);
```

Then it would instead befriend a non-template function `operator==`, separate and distinct from the function template, which would be incorrect.

(The relevant standardese is found in §14.5.4 [temp.friends]/p1.)